# If I weigh 250 lbs on earth, how much do I weigh on the moon?

Tags: algebra-precalculus

One of my homework questions is to determine how much a 250 lb person weighs on the moon.  I first googled a calculator for this and found that the weight is 41.5 lbs.  So I tried to derive it myself and I cannot seem to get the correct answer.

Here is what I'm doing:

$$F=ma$$

I first converted $250$ lbs to Newtons:

$$250lb\frac{4.448 N}{1 lb}=1112N$$

So I then figured I'd plug values into the the formula $F=ma$

$$1112N=113.5kg(1.6\frac{m}{s^2})$$

But no matter how I solve this, I cannot seem to get the correct answer.  What am I doing wrong?

Comment: @Clayton yeah its $1.6\frac{m}{s^2}$  I wrote that in my attempt to solve it.

Comment: Where does your last equation come from? $113.5 \times 1.6 \neq 1112$.

Comment: So what is confusing? You know the conversion from pounds to Newtons. Calculate the force on the moon, now convert back to pounds.

Comment: What’s a $lb$ ?

Comment: If **your mass** is 125 pounds on Earth, then your mass is 125 pounds on the Moon, on Mars and anywhere else. Your mass is expressed in kilograms (kg), or in pounds if you prefer. Your **weight** is a force and is expressed in newtons (N). Your weight depends on your mass and on the gravity where you are.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$1112$ N is the force on earth: it’s (approximately) $$113.5\text{ kg}\cdot 9.8\frac{\text{m}}{\text{s}^2}\;.$$ To get the force on the moon you want

$$113.5\text{ kg}\cdot 1.625\frac{\text{m}}{\text{s}^2}\;,$$

which you’ll then have to convert to pounds. Of course you could simply multiply $250$ by the ratio of gravitational accelerations, $\dfrac{1.625}{9.8}$.

Comment: Thanks so much!  The point of this assignment is to get comfortable with dimensional analysis so that's why I'm going about it the more difficult way.  I just want to make sure that I understand it.

Comment: I didn't get quite $41.5$ but I did get $40.827$

Comment: @inquisitor: You’re welcome! I get about $41.4541$ if I multiply $250$ by that last fraction.

Answer (score 2):

$$
{W_{\tiny earth} \over W_{\tiny moon}}\
=\
{\quad{\displaystyle{G\,{mM_{\it moon} \over R_{\tiny moon}^{2}}}}\quad
\over
{\displaystyle{G\,{mM_{\it earth} \over R_{\tiny earth}^{2}}}}}\
=\
\left(R_{\tiny earth} \over R_{\tiny moon}\right)^{2}
\,{M_{\tiny moon} \over M_{\tiny earth}}
$$

$$
\begin{array}{rcrrcr}
M_{\it moon} & = & 7.36 \times 10^{22}\ {\rm Kg}\,,
&\qquad
R_{\it moon} & = & 1737\ {\rm Km}\,,
\\
M_{\it earth} & = &6 \times 10^{24}\ {\rm Kg}\,,
&\qquad
R_{\it earth} & = & 6371\ {\rm Km}\,,
\end{array}
$$

$$
{W_{\tiny earth} \over W_{\tiny moon}}
=
\left(6371 \over 1737\right)^{2}\,{7.36 \over 600}
=
\color{#ff0000}{\Large 0.16502211055021}
$$

$W_{\tiny earth} = 250\ {\rm lb}$:
$$
W_{\tiny moon}
=
{W_{\tiny earth} \over 0.16502211055021}
=
{250\ {\rm lb}
 \over
 0.16502211055021}
=
{\large\color{#ff0000}{41.2555276375525}\ {\rm lb}}
$$

Answer (score 1):

You just need to find the weight force the person creates when on the moon and then multiply the mass of the person by the ratio of $F_{moon}$ to $F_{earth}$