# A suitcase weighs one kilogram plus half of its weight. How much does the suitcase weigh?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, arithmetic

> A suitcase weighs one kilogram plus half of its weight. How much does the suitcase weigh?

1. $1.333\dots$ kilograms
2. $1.5$ kilograms
3. $1.666\dots$ kilograms
4. $2$ kilograms
5. Cannot be determined from the given data.

---

My attempt:

First, I was confused between `weigh` and `weight`. I did google, I found that :
"Weigh" is a verb "to weigh" or to determine the heaviness we have to weigh that object. "Weight" is a noun. It is a measure of heaviness of an object. Still, confused, is weigh equal to mass, it should not be because, mass is less that weights of an object, but here weigh is more than weight of given object.

I have read this post [If I weigh 250 lbs on earth, how much do I weigh on the moon?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/529264/if-i-weigh-250-lbs-on-earth-how-much-do-i-weigh-on-the-moon) and try to calculate weigh$=1.0899$, which should be wrong as we have not given moon here. :)

> Can you explain it, please?

Comment: Why voted down?

Comment: This isn't a question about weight/mass , it's just algebra.  $x=1+\frac 12 x$. (note:  I did not vote this down).

Comment: "Weigh" means to have a specified weight.

Comment: @lulu, That was my silly mistake, I was laughing, when I read this as my weight is one kg plus half of my weight. :-o (recursive)

Comment: Make sure to inform your instructor that the kilogram is a unit of *mass* and not a unit of weight (which is a force, e.g., Newtons, lbs, etc.).  Man that always bothers me..

Comment: @tilper, thanks, good, that's was TIFR yesterday exam question. :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let $w$ kilograms be its weight.

The given condition states that

\begin{align}
w &= 1 + \frac12 w \\
w &= 2
\end{align}

Hence (4) the suitcase weighs two kilograms.

Comment: Thanks for nice explanation.